# Hegyi Index on R Plot

Tags: r, loops, indexing

I want to use for my data the Hegyi Index without siplab. So far that's above my possibilities. 
I use R Studio on Windows 7.
The Formula is 
[image: formula]

So, in a certain radius, called CZR, around the target tree, take all the trees there and divide their diameter d through the diameter or the target tree. Then divide the result through the distance between both. This will be repeated for each tree in the Competition Zone. Those values shall be added and the value written in a new column in the dataframe. Then this should be repeated again.

So far, I have my data

```
`Plot 1`<-read.csv
CZR<-6
tree0<-`Plot 1`$ID[`Plot 1`$SpNr=="1"&`Plot 1`$X>5&`Plot 1`$X<25&`Plot 1`$Y>5&`Plot 1`$Y<25] # 5 m from margin

x0<-NULL
y0<-NULL
spec0<-NULL
d0<-NULL
pos11<-NULL
pos12<-NULL
posXY<-NULL

for(n in 1:length(tree0)){
  x0[n]<-`Plot 1`$X[`Plot 1`$ID==tree0[n]]
  y0[n]<-`Plot 1`$Y[`Plot 1`$ID==tree0[n]]
  spec0[n]<-`Plot 1`$Sp[`Plot 1`$ID==tree0[n]]
  d0[n]<-`Plot 1`$dbh[`Plot 1`$ID==tree0[n]]
  pos11[n]<-`Plot 1`$xy[`Plot 1`$ID==tree0[n]]
  pos12[n]<-`Plot 1`$xy[`Plot 1`$ID==tree0[n]]
  posXY[n]<-`Plot 1`$xy[`Plot 1`$ID==tree0[n]]
}
```

I wasn't sure what's working, so I added the x and y coordinates and the complex plane.

```
ref_tree<-cbind(tree0, spec0, d0, x0, y0); ref_tree # all the ref trees 
ref_tree<-as.data.frame(ref_tree)
cbind(ref_tree, posXY) #if I don't change to data.frame, everything becomes a complex number

plot(`Plot 1`$xy, main="Treecoordinates Plot 1", xlim=c(0,30),ylim = c(0,30),
     xlab="Osten in Metern", ylab= "Norden in Metern",
     cex=sqrt(`Plot 1`$dbh))
```

And now I have many strings I tried to follow with bad results. Any idea how I could continue here to compare only the trees to the target one in the CZR?

Comment: For most of us the symbol `read.csv` is a function. You appear to have also named a data-object with that name. Not such a great strategy.

Comment: You should provide at least the output of `dput(head(get('Plot 1')))`. You should realize that most beginners with R think that the "length" function refers to rows, when in fact it refers to columns of dataframes. so it's likely that you loop is doing completely incorrect things (and throwing errors.) You probably want `for(n in 1:nrow(tree0)){ ...`

Comment: you are completely right. I corrected this before, I just repeated this mistake here. Thanks.The read.csv is just a short version, because my path is quite long.

Comment: Not sure what that last comment with reference to "before" means. I hope you don't think we should be going back and searching all of your prior questions.